# Spilt Comma From Value In a Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
$myarray = attr_group => array(
             "group_id" => array(
                    "attr" => array(
                          [0] => "test1"
                          [1] => "test2"
                          [3] => "test1,test2,test3,test4"
                          [4] => "test1,test5,test6"
                     )
               )
           )
```

How could I explode the values from the "attr" array onto different lines and then continue using the array if I were to call it like this:

`$myarray[attr_group][group_id][attr]`

And I want the final result of my array to look something like this:

```
$myarray = attr_group => array(
             "group_id" => array(
                    "attr" => array(
                          [0] => "test1"
                          [1] => "test2"
                          [3] => "test3"
                          [4] => "test4"
                          [5] => "test5"
                          [6] => "test6"
                     )
               )
           )
```

Maybe this isnt possible, but I thought it would be worth a post! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you meant `[5] => "test5"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$myarray = array(
    "attr_group" => array(
        "group_id" => array(
            "attr" => array(
                0 => "test1",
                1 => "test2",
                3 => "test1,test2,test3,test4",
                4 => "test1,test5,test6"
            )
        )
    )
);

$attr = &$myarray["attr_group"]["group_id"]["attr"];
$attr = array_values(array_unique(explode(",", implode(",", $attr))));

print_r($myarray);
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/135783)